# Minimal configuration for VoltDB to be able to show durability and HA

Tags: database, relational-database, voltdb

My exposure to NoSQL or NewSQL/NeoSQL database servers is extremely limited, only theoretical. I've worked with traditional RDBMSs (like MySQL, Postgres) and directory-server (OpenLDAP), with and without replication.

My application stack is based on JBoss, and I've been tasked with setting up a minimal demo (with our application) that can demonstrate durability and high-availability of data, in VoltDB. Performance testing, is not an objective at all.

Have been going thru the [VoltDB Planning Guide](http://downloads.voltdb.com/documentation/PlanningGuide.pdf), but I am confused between the "+1" or "x2" in terms of number of servers (or VoltDB instances) required. Especially given these 2 statements:-

> The easiest way to size hardware for a K-Safe cluster is to size the
>   initial instance of the database, based on projected throughput and
>   capacity, then multiply the number of servers by the number of
>   replicas you desire (that is, the K-Safety value plus one).
>
> **Rule of Thumb**
>
> When using K-Safety, configure the number of cluster nodes as a whole multiple of the number of copies of the database
>   (that is, K+1)

**Questions:**

1. Now, let's say that I need 1 server given capacity/throughput
   requirements. So, to be able to have durability and
   high-availability, do I need: 2, 3 or 4 servers ?
2. OTOH, using just 1 server, what all key features of VoltDB would I
   have to forgo ?
3. Is there any relationship (or conflict) between VoltDB's full
   disk-persistence and snapshots ? Say, the availability of disk-persistence
   removes the need for snapshots ?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you use 2 servers, you can keep a synchronous replica of data to protect from data loss, much like a RAID1 hard drive. Your data is double-safe, but there is a catch with availability. With only two servers, it's impossible to differentiate a network split from a failed node. In some cases, VoltDB will shut down a live node when another fails to ensure there will be no split brain. With 3 nodes, this won't be an issue and the cluster will remain available after any single node failure (with k=1 or k=2).
2. With just 1 server, all you lose is the multiple copies of data on multiple servers and the high-availability features that allow VoltDB to continue running after a node failure. You still have all of the other VoltDB features, including full disk persistence.

Comment: Thanks John. So, k=1 is definitely not a configuration that could be used in production. What k=1, there is no way that VoltDB could use a quorum device -- s.a. a 3rd server not running VoltDB, but some other application software or maybe a very low end machine, with much lesser RAM requirements ?

Comment: Also, added a follow-on question. Would be great if you could answer.